# What's the meaning of DStream.foreachRDD function?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In spark streaming, every batch interval of data always generate one and only one RDD, why do we use `foreachRDD()` to foreach RDD? RDD is only one, needn't foreach.
In my testing, I never see RDD more than one.

Comment: Did you actually understand the answer in the end?

Comment: http://asyncified.io/2017/02/10/why-you-might-be-misusing-sparks-streaming-api/

Answer (score 58):

A `DStream` or "discretized stream" is an abstraction that breaks a continuous stream of data into small chunks. This is called "microbatching".  Each microbatch becomes an RDD that is given to Spark for further processing. **There's one and only one RDD** produced for each DStream at each batch interval.

An RDD is a distributed collection of data. Think of it as a set of pointers to where the actual data is in a cluster.

`DStream.foreachRDD` is an "output operator" in Spark Streaming. It allows you to access the underlying RDDs of the DStream to execute actions that do something practical with the data. For example, using `foreachRDD` you could write data to a database.

The little mind twist here is to understand that a DStream is a time-bound collection. Let me contrast this with a classical collection: Take a list of users and apply a foreach to it:

```
val userList: List[User] = ???
userList.foreach{user => doSomeSideEffect(user)}
```

This will apply the side-effecting function `doSomeSideEffect` to each element of the `userList` collection.

Now, let's say that we don't know all the users now, so we cannot build a list of them. Instead, we have a stream of users, like people arriving into a coffee shop during morning rush:

```
val userDStream: DStream[User] = ???
userDstream.foreachRDD{usersRDD => 
    usersRDD.foreach{user => serveCoffee(user)}
}
```

Note that:

- the `DStream.foreachRDD` gives you an `RDD[User]`, **not a single user**. Going back to our coffee example, that is the collection of users that arrived during some interval of time.
- to access single elements of the collection, we need to further operate on the RDD. In this case, I'm using a `rdd.foreach` to serve coffee to each user.

To think about execution: We might have a cluster of baristas making coffee. Those are our executors. Spark Streaming takes care of making a small batch of users (or orders) and Spark will distribute the work across the baristas, so that we can parallelize the coffee making and speed up the coffee serving.

Comment: @guo see also my presentation on Spark Streaming. It has an animated explanation of how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgvYg-0OXkU

Comment: Thank you for the correction regarding partition/RDD. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: What does seem weird is that the abstraction provides an `Iterator[RDD[T]]`. Is there a case where more than one DStream will be available during such iteration?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Where do you see that `DStream` provides an `Iterator[RDD[T]]`? What do you mean with 'more than one DStream'?  RDD maybe?

Comment: @maasg I still don't understand! As you said, "**There's one and only one RDD** produced for each DStream at each batch interval", it needn't API of `foreachRDD()` to foreach RDD, because of only one RDD, `foreachRDD()` can named `getRDD()` and return RDD object. Your example can modify like this:  　　　`val userDStream: DStream[User] = ???` 　　　
`userDstream.getRDD.foreach{user => serveCoffee(user)}`

Comment: @Guo, using the example of the coffee shop. Imagine we have DStream[User] at the following time intervals: 9:00 :(alice, bart, mike, gerard), 9:15: (bruno, guo, ana), 9:30: (eva, lisa).  What should `userDstream.getRDD`  return when you start the shop at 6:00 ? How can you process the users of 9:00 or 9:30?

Comment: @maasg your mean that  use 15min as a time interval, 9:00 generate a RDD, 9:15 generate a RDD, 9:30 generate a RDD, you can use `foreachRDD()` to foreach three RDD(contains 9:00, 9:15, 9:30), but suppose time is 9:30 now, the RDDs of 9:00 and 9:15 was process before, if you use `foreachRDD()`, you only can process one RDD of 9:30, how do you process RDDs before 9:30 at 9:30? the data or RDDs before 9:30 is disappearing at 9:30, isn't it? In Spark steaming, every time interval process current batch interval of data, why do you process RDD of 6:00 at 9:30, RDD of 6:00 shoud be process at 6:00.

Comment: @Guo, no, that's not what I meant. I wanted to let you see that the foreachRDD it time-bound. You should understand `foreachRDD` as `scheduleOperationOnRddForEachTimeInterval(rdd => operation(rdd))`.

Comment: @Guo did you see the video above?

Comment: @maasg thank you for your answer! I go to see video first.

Comment: @maasg what if you didn't do .foreachRDD and just userDStream.map(), wouldn't that perform the operation on each user still?

Comment: @coolbreeze like in Spark, if there're no actions the transformations are not materialized. Further more, if we don't register an output operation (like `foreachRDD`) on the Streaming Context, it will throw an exception when we try to start it:  `No output operations registered, so nothing to execute`

Comment: Has this changed in spark 2.4, that foreachrdd is called per batch interval? i have a print statement in `foreachRDD` but only prints once despite many batch intervals have passed.